# ProblemWithTheJar the .jar - images do not show up

Tags: java

Problem is the following - I am writing a program with Eclipse in java..
The resulting folder structure is main project folder: Animal Classification/  inside of it:  bin/ , images/, pics/    in the bin/ folder : users/metropolia/allClasses.class

Program starts normally and works -> images are in the folders images/ and pics/ -> they are used by users.metropolia.Hieararchy

But when I create a .jar out of it either through Eclipse or through CMD.exe -> in the folder different from the source folder the jar does not show images even though they are packed inside of it. Inside the Hierarchy.class the path to the images is ("images/name.jpg" or "pics/name.jpg").

Then I tried to use the ClassLoader.getSystemResource("images/name.jpg") - but now the eclipse and the cmd.exe give warnings and dont start the program -> NullPointerException in thread main = mistake in the line where ClassLoader static is used...

I would really appreciate any help

### Update:

http://users.metropolia.fi/~artemm/

Download the code from there plz 
It can be downloaded as SFX-archive or if you are afraid of viruses just download usual RAR archive

I really appreciate your help

Main class is in users/metropolia/Program.java

### Update 2:

@MockerTim

THank you very much for your help - now everything works. Moreover, I managed to find one more snag - it didnt call for the images, because the call was : "Fish.jpg" and the picture was : "fish.jpg" - no wonder it could not find anything and gave mistakes.

THank you very much once again, I really appreciate!

Comment: What's the actual error message? In any case, I've always used `getResourceAsStream` for resources within a jar.

Comment: @Artem Moskalev: If you use the result of `getSystemResource()` in combination with the `File` class, then you're out of luck with Jar files. The contents of a Jar file cannot be accessed with the `File` class. In addition to the actual error message, please also show more code (how you access the images).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Swing: Displaying images from within a Jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127/java-swing-displaying-images-from-within-a-jar) (or about a hundred other questions about loading images from JAR files.)

Comment: This is the snippet of Hierarchy.java...images are loaded in MyDrawPanel class and Hierarchy::start() method

Comment: I failed to compile your code. Have you tried to compile this code before publishing it here? If you place any code, it must be [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Otherwise it doesn't help to solve your problem. The full stack trace may also help.

Comment: THe problem is - the whole application contains much more code - is it possible to stick it as a file??

Comment: This is just the main class connected from the Program.class in its main method - it contains the ImageIcon("") constructors

Comment: You can add code of all needed files. Just devide it by comments. See [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000116/java-generics-wildcards-question/6027155#6027155), for example. It's hard to find the mistake in your code if we can't even compile it. You should modify your code to fit [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: http://users.metropolia.fi/~artemm/ Here you can download the whole thing its my "web site" Main file - users.metropolia.Program.java

Comment: http://users.metropolia.fi/~artemm/
Check my Code over there
It is in archives RAR
THe main class is Program.java in users/metropolia

Comment: You are Welcome! But, Do not remove your initial question from your post. Let people see the initial question. Make updates to your question. Place your thanks in comments only. See the [FAQ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using incorrect paths.

You should use the following paths in your code:
`../../images/name.jpg` and `../../pics/name.jgp`, respectively.

As [Nate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118133/nate) mentioned, you can start you path with "/", and use `/images/name.jpg` and `/pics/name.jpg`, respectively.

When you use `images/name.jpg` path in the class `users.metropolia.Hieararchy`, your code tries to find file `name.jpg` in the folder `users/metropolia/images`. And, of course, it fails.

See [Locating resources in Java](http://littletutorials.com/2008/03/26/locating-resources-in-java/) for details.

Here is the simple example:

```
package users.metropolia;

import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class IconManager {
    /** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
    public static ImageIcon loadImageIcon(String path) {
        URL imgURL = IconManager.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
                return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Using absolute (to jar) paths
        ImageIcon icon3 = loadImageIcon("/pics/spider.jpg");
        ImageIcon icon4 = loadImageIcon("/imagess/ant.jpg");
    }
}
```

### Update:

I've downloaded your code (from [your link](http://users.metropolia.fi/~artemm/)), and added the above `IconManager` class and used its `loadImageIcon()` method to initialize your `anImages` array and `MyDrawPanel` class.
Now your progam looks like this:

[image]

**The changes, that I've made to your code:**

In class `Hierarchy`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  //anImages[i] = new ImageIcon("/images/" + options[i] + ".jpg");
    anImages[i] = IconManager.loadImageIcon("/images/" + options[i] + ".jpg");
    listObj[i] = new RendObject(options[i], anImages[i]);
}
```

In class `MyDrawPanel`:

```
public MyDrawPanel(String x) {
  //picture = new ImageIcon(x).getImage();
    picture = IconManager.loadImageIcon(x).getImage();
}
```

And, of course, I removed "generic" from `JComboBox` where needed.

**Remark:** To make your program show selected image instead of spider image, you should modify your program further.

Comment: Seems like it'd be less brittle to use absolute paths and just load them as resource streams.

Comment: Or reference paths as "/images/name.jpg", etc. - the leading / tells the classloader to start at the "root" of the JAR.

Comment: @Nate Right you are! I'll add it to the example.

Comment: @DaveNewton Sometimes it simply shorter to use relative paths.

Comment: @Nate That's what I said--that's an absolute path for a resource stream.

Comment: I did like you daid guys still doesnt work - NullPointerException at javax.swing.ImageIcon <init>(ImageIcon.205), users.metropolia.Hierarchy.start(Hierarchy.java: 75)

Answer (score 0):

To read a file when you create a Jar file in the META-INF folder you must create a 'INDEX.LIST' file '.LIST' is the extension  of the file.

in this 'INDEX.LIST' you describe the path to your file

Comment: WHat is that and how to use that?